# Apollo-client update cache variable: orderby name doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a mutation of new product. I update cache with cache.writeQuery and I want to order the product by name. My code doesn't work, always the new product is the last item (see the picture) . I can see the error. Could you help me? What is wrong?

COMPONENT NEW PRODUCT

```
import { gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client'

const NEW_PRODUCT = gql`
mutation newProduct($input: ProductInput) {
  newProduct(input:$input) {
    id
    name
    stock
    price
    date_creation
  }
}`

const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
  query getProducts{
  getProducts{
    id
    name
    stock
    price
  }
}`

const NouProducte = () => {

  const [newProduct] = useMutation(NEW_PRODUCT, {
    update(cache, { data: { newProduct } }) {
      const { getProducts } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_PRODUCTS })
      cache.writeQuery({
        query: GET_PRODUCTS,
        data: {
          getProducts: [...getProducts, newProduct],
          variables: { orderBy: name }
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can order-by on local cache with apollo. However, this is how I would resolve the issue:

```
  data: {
          getProducts: [...getProducts, newProduct]
        }
```

In this line of code you are adding all the original products, then the new product to the end of the array that you are writing to your cache.

A quick way to fix this is sort the array before writing it to the cache. The following compare sorts arrays by objects name attribute

```
  function compare(a, b) {
    // Use toUpperCase() to ignore character casing
    const productA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    const productB = b.name.toUpperCase();

    let comparison = 0;
    if (productA > productB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (productA < productB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
  }
```

Then use it on your array to sort.

```
  data: {
          getProducts: [...getProducts, newProduct].sort(compare)
        }
```

Comment: The cache doesn't have any magic functions on it. It's just a store of data that can be manipulated. This is a correct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Why do you ever expected sorting?**

You're using a **low level access** to cache then **you're responsible for providing data in the same shape** as expected from remote source.

In this case **if source data was sorted you have to pass sorted data to be written**. Just get `getProducts`, push `newProduct` into the array, sort it and finally use sorted array in `writeQuery`.